# Proving that the measure of a set of points in a string that appears infinitely often is one

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

$\forall$ real $x \in (0,1], \exists$ $0,1$ valued sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ s.t. $x = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}\frac{1}{2^i}$. Ruling out the sequences with trailing $1's$ will make this assignment unique. Let $a_{i}a_{i+1}...a_{i+k-2}a_{i+k-1}$ be a fixed string of zeros and ones of length $k$. I want to show that the measure of the set of points in $(0,1]$ for which the string appears infinitely often in their binary expansion is $1$.

I was thinking this problem could be done with the Borel-Cantelli lemmas, and if possible that is how I would like to solve this problem, but I am a little unsure. Obviously by one of the lemmas if we get a sum thats infinite then the probability is one. The help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma here.
For $\omega$ in $(0,1]$, let $X_n(\omega)$ denote the $n$th digit in the binary expansion of $\omega$. The random variables $\{X_n\}$ are mutually independent. Your first impulse might be to define event $E_n$ to be the event that your fixed string starts at position $n$ of the binary expansion, i.e.,
$$ E_n := \{ X_n = a_i, X_{n+1} = a_{i+1}, \dots , X_{n+k-1} = a_{i+k-1}\}$$
The $E_n$'s as defined above have the same constant probability, so you've got your sum of infinity -- but the events as defined are not independent. (Why not?)  To fix this, it suffices to alter the definition of $E_n$ slightly.

Comment: Are we just essentially breaking this string into sub strings and then using the fact that $k$ is a finite length so taking the sum of them will result in infinity?

Comment: The $E_n$ as defined above are not independent because event $E_n$ and event $E_{n+1}$ will (partially) refer to the same set of $X$'s. To avoid this overlapping, you can alter which $X$'s are referred to within $E_n$. No breaking up of the fixed string is needed...